# Can't pass 'complex objects' as parameters in Design view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created my own Validation controllers, to work with my own User Controls.

My Problem :

the classic validators accept parameters in 'design view', e.g.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtFirstname" runat="server" />
```

and I'd like to do the same in my controls, but it appears when I pass 'ControlToValidate' a control ID, I get this error :

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl'
>   from its string representation 'txtFirstname' for the
>   'ControlToValidate' property.

What 'pattern' do I need to implement to ensure I can make the most of my 'ascx' page instead of having to hook up everything in my 'ascx.cs' code-behind page.

p.s. I'm calling the 'tags' I create on the 'ascx' page 'design view', but I think that is probably the wrong term, which I suspect is half the reason I cant find anythign on google for this.

Comment: I found someone asking this question on another site, which is also exactly what I'm trying to do with _normal user controls_ , but with classic ASP.NET (instead of the MVC stuff he mentions with different controls) : http://forums.asp.net/t/1247195.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

Your code simply should look something like this (all in the `.ascx`):

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtFirstName" 
      Text="Enter a value" 
      runat="server"/>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
      ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
      Text="Required Field!" 
      runat="server"/>
```

I'm guessing that you're **not** placing the `RequiredFieldValidator` in the same scope - causing this problem.

Comment: I am using my own Custom Controls, that I've created, extending them from System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.WebControl, and my custom Validators extend System.Web.UI.Control, so your answer is of no use. I am not using the stock controls or validators.

Comment: @Nnoel - Then this may be your problem, you may be doing something which isn't ordinary, and we certainly can't see it here.

Comment: ok, simple instructions to recreate my problem : 1. create your own custom control [control1] (extend textbox if you like), then 2. create another custom control [control2] (extend System.Web.UI.Control) and create a property of typeof(control1) in control2, and then ensure you can pass control1 to control2 via the 'ascx' page alone. Simples. I have other controls that need to do the same thing, like an 'image preloader' that needs access to each control that needs images preloaded, all have to be 'linked' in the code behind alone, passing as the parameters in as 'ascx' doesn't work.